# defining a general string in visual studio c++

Tags: string, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I have written a project in C++ VS2010. It has some GUIs and then I would like to pass some variables(strings) from a function to another. To be precise, I have defined a two checkbox s as

```
    this->M1_GR1->AutoSize = true;
    this->M1_GR1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 9, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
    this->M1_GR1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(7, 27);
    this->M1_GR1->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(2, 4, 2, 4);
    this->M1_GR1->Name = L"M1_GR1";
    this->M1_GR1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(73, 19);
    this->M1_GR1->TabIndex = 95;
    this->M1_GR1->Text = L"M1-GR1";
    this->M1_GR1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this->M1_GR1->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this,&config::M1_GR1_CheckedChanged);
```

and

```
    this->M1_GR2->AutoSize = true;
    this->M1_GR2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 9,System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,             static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
    this->M1_GR2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(7, 63);
    this->M1_GR2->Margin = System::Windows::Forms::Padding(2, 4, 2, 4);
    this->M1_GR2->Name = L"M1_GR2";
    this->M1_GR2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(73, 19);
    this->M1_GR2->TabIndex = 96;
    this->M1_GR2->Text = L"M1-GR2";
    this->M1_GR2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this->M1_GR2->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this,&config::M1_GR2_CheckedChanged);
```

and then there is a condition for these checkbox. If user select one of then the other will be grayed out and then one of strings `M1_GR1->Text` or `M1_GR1->Text` will be saved.

```
private: System::Void M1_GR1_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            String^ M1_GR;
            if (M1_GR1->Checked == true) {
                M1_GR2->Enabled = false;
                M1_GR = M1_GR1->Text;
            }
            if (M1_GR1->Checked == false) {
                M1_GR2->Enabled = true;
            }
        }

private: System::Void M1_GR2_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            String ^ M1_GR;
            if (M1_GR2->Checked == true) {
                M1_GR1->Enabled = false;
                M1_GR = "M1-GR2";
            }
            if (M1_GR2->Checked == false) {
                M1_GR1->Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

Now if user checked the box behind one, I would like to save one string in a `*.csv` file, say `M1-GR1`:

```
private: System::Void config_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             load_csv();
         }
         void load_csv()
         {
             StreamReader^ sr = File::OpenText("config.csv");
             String^ buff = "";
             array<Char>^chars = {','};
             array<String^>^ arr;

             while (buff = sr->ReadLine()) {
                 arr = buff->Split(chars);
                 if (buff!=""){
                     M1_GR = arr[0];
                 }
                 else
                 {

                 }
             }
             sr->Close();
         }
```

When I wanted to debug the code I have following error:

```
config.h(1800): error C2065: 'M1_GR' : undeclared identifier
```

Would you please let me know how could I pass the string `M1_GR` into `M1_GR`?

Thanks a lot for your comments in advance!

Ps. A sample version is uploaded in the following link. pass: test

http://www.mediafire.com/download/3j5302m17ngvrvn/test.zip

Comment: Did you miss a _forward declaration_ for `M1_GR`, or do you just have some misconceptions?

Comment: Would you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: _@Saber_ I can't with just this narrow informatin. Please try to make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) fro your question. Chances are high, you'll find out yourself, what's going wrong this way.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The rest of code is ok and works great. I just want to know how one can save the mentioned data depending on user choice into `config.csv`? That means how one can define a string that pass the data from `M1_GR1_CheckedChanged` or ``M1_GR2_CheckedChanged`` to `config_Load`?

Comment: _@Saber_ I have no clue, what you're actually asking about. We're not interested in the _rest of the code_, but that you just give us a minimal sample that reproduces your compiler error, and why you don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, it seems like you are getting that error because you are trying to use   M1_GR   out of the blue, without declaring it (as the error message describes).
If I understand your question correctly and you are trying to save the    M1_GR   string, that you saved upon one of your check-boxes being checked, in the .csv file, then I would change a couple of things:

1. Pass    M1_GR    (by reference) as an argument to both    M1_GR1_CheckedChanged()    and    M1_GR2_CheckedChanged()    like this

`private: System::Void M1_GR1_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e, String% M1_GR) {

            if (M1_GR1->Checked == true) {
                M1_GR2->Enabled = false;
                M1_GR = M1_GR1->Text;
            }
            if (M1_GR1->Checked == false) {
                M1_GR2->Enabled = true;
            }
        }`

private: System::Void M1_GR2_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e, String% M1_GR) {
            if (M1_GR2->Checked == true) {
                M1_GR1->Enabled = false;
                M1_GR = "M1-GR2";
            }
            if (M1_GR2->Checked == false) {
                M1_GR1->Enabled = true;
            }
        }

The way you originally have it declared inside both functions makes it just local to the functions, ergo it doesn't really exist after your functions lose their scope.

2. As for no. 1 above, pass a string reference to your    config_Load()    function and pass the same argument to your    load_csv()    function (in this case, I would pass it by value since it looks like you are not interested in whether it gets modified or not).
3. Lastly, I would slightly change how load_csv() is implemented like this:

`void load_csv(String M1_GR)
         {
           //StreamReader^ sr = File::OpenText("config.csv");
           //--Use File::OpenWrite() instead of File::OpenText() 
           //--OpenText() opens the file just for reading yet we want to write to it
           //--Explore just Open() for more flexibility`

```
         FileStream^ fs = File::OpenWrite("config.csv");

         //-- I didn't understand what the code below is trying to do so I commented it out
         /*String^ buff = "";
         array<Char>^chars = {','};
         array<String^>^ arr;

         while (buff = sr->ReadLine()) {
             arr = buff->Split(chars);
             if (buff!=""){
                 M1_GR = arr[0];
             }
             else
             {

             }
         }
         sr->Close();*/

         try {
           //Better memory allocation can be achieved by allocating just enough bytes one need
           array<Byte>^ M1_GR_bytes = (gcnew UTF8Encoding(true)->GetBytes(M1_GR);

           fs->Write(M1_GR_bytes , 0, M1_GR_bytes->Length); //--Write M1_GR to your file
         }
         finally {
           if (fs) delete (IDisposable^) fs;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Regarding your answer:
`String^` is for VS2010 instead of `String%`.
after running I have two errors:
`error C3352: 'void Arbeitsenergieumsatz::config::M1_CW2_CheckedChanged(System::Object ^,System::EventArgs ^,System::String ^)' : the specified function does not match the delegate type 'void (System::Object ^,System::EventArgs ^)'`

and another one is regarding `String^ M1_GR`:
`error C2065: 'M1_GR' : undeclared identifier`

Comment: @Saber, the second error looks like there is inconsistency between how you defined the function    M1_CW2_CheckedChanged()    and how you are called it. I would make sure they match. It looks like the number of arguments are different. Did you pass the     M1_GR    argument by reference in both places?

Comment: I did, but the error is related to 
`this->M1_GR1->CheckedChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this,&config::M1_GR1_CheckedChanged);`

Comment: I would have to see that other piece of code to know what's really going on there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helps. I have uploaded a sample version that creates the mentioned error. It is in last part of question.